# Select last inserted data from table

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

First  I tried to look for the answer on here(stackoverflow) as well as other sites like a microsoft forum, but couldn't find anything that answered my question. Or I just couldn't understand.

I'm working on a (school)project I got from a company, they gave me acces to their database. In here is a table with data from a sensor that registers stuff every once in a while.

Now  my question is: I want to get the last data inserted into the table and show just one row (echo or print, I dont really mind how, I just want it to work and to understand it.)

The table looks as followed:
[Tablename= container_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2iXr.png)

I want to show the last inserted data in COL 3.
Is there a way to do this with the table the company provided me with?

Comment: by "last inserted": Do you mean the last (technically) inserted record, or the record with the youngest timestamp? If the later one is the case, see the given answer.

Comment: yes, by "last inserted" I mean the last inserted record. In this case this is the one which is saying "2018-03-16 15:00:04;6  678;1018  2". COL1 is a varchar by the way, maybe it is an option to convert this into a timestamp first, and then selecting COL3 which has the latest timestamp or something?

Answer (score 0):

Using phpmyadmin you can:

```
Select * from your_table order by col1 desc Limit 1;
```

This way you'll only have the last entry

Comment: Sorting does not provide the latest record inserted. We don't know, if the timestamps are related to the insert time. (In fact they are measurement results, which can be inserted at any time after collecting them at the given timestamp) - So older records might be inserted later, depending on update frequency / connection quality and the like.

Comment: Oh yes that's true, i haven't thought about this. My bad.